# How to know weathere the page is started navigating or not?

Tags: gwt

I am facing this Problem Since last day .Here it is and need help of you .

I am working on a web application, and Sending and retrieving data from Server through an RPC .

My problem is that If I clicked on any action , i am sending  an request and if I Clicked on any other links  which are navigate the page to other view, without retrieving data of first RPC i am getting the Exception because of that navigation .

I need to avoid it by knowing the navigation .

here i written the code .Lets check once :

```
    @Override
public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {


      if (exception instanceof StatusCodeException) {
        if (((StatusCodeException) exception).getStatusCode() == 403) {
            MyExcclass.showMessage("session expired");
            logout();
        } else {
            MyExcclass.showInformation("unable to perform the action");
        }
    }
    exception.printStackTrace();

}
```

I am getting the unable to perform action .

Comment: Can you post full error/exception stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is unloaded when the RPC response comes back, you should see a `StatusCodeException` with `getStatusCode()` of `0`.

If you want, you can preemptively cancel the requests within a `Window.addCloseHandler`. This means you'd have to provide your own `RpcRequestBuilder` for each remote service to keep the `Request` instances around (in a `Set`) until they're completed (you'd wrap the `RequestCallback` to remove the associated `Request` from the `Set` in `onSuccess` or `onFailure`); and in your `CloseHandler` you'd iterate on the `Set` to `cancel()` all pending `Request`. Overall, it's easier to handle the `getStatusCode() == 0` case in your `AsyncCallback.onFailure` methods.